# JavaFx прижать блоки к верху и к низу окна

Tags: java, javafx

Мне нужно сделать, чтобы у меня три label были вверху окна (друг за другом) в полную ширину, один внизу окна, а в центре находилась форма. Может мне кто-то дать пример кода, где это реализовано на JavaFx?

Смотрю гугл: везде примеры с центрированием, таблицей или borderPane. Вот что-то никак не разберусь, хотя задачка, казалось бы, простая.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: И чем вам BorderPane не подошел? В верхний блок вставляете VBox и добавляете в него три Label, в нижний блок можно сразу ваш четвертый Label,а в центральную еще один подходящий контейнер, в который вставите свою форму.

Comment: @Maxim, да, наверное подойдет. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для размещения используйте `Scene Builder`. Там можно легко разметь объекты так, как вы хотите.